# what's the difference between these two numpy array shape?

Tags: python, numpy

```
In [136]: s = np.array([[1,0,1],[0,1,1],[0,0,1],[1,1,1]])                                                          

In [137]: s                                                                                                        
Out[137]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])

In [138]: x = s[0:1]                                                                                               

In [139]: x.shape                                                                                                  
Out[139]: (1, 3)

In [140]: y = s[0]                                                                                                 

In [141]: y.shape                                                                                                  
Out[141]: (3,)

In [142]: x                                                                                                        
Out[142]: array([[1, 0, 1]])

In [143]: y                                                                                                        
Out[143]: array([1, 0, 1])
```

In the above code, x's shape is (1,3) and y's shape is(3,).

```
(1,3): 1 row and 3 columns
(3,): How many rows and columns in this case?
```

Does (3,) represent 1-dimension array?

In practice, if I want to iterate through the matrix row by row, which way should I go?

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    row = x[i]
    # OR
    row = x[i:i+1]
```

Comment: `for row in s:` is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can get the number of dimensions of an `numpy` array `array` through `len(array.shape)`.

An array with some dimensions of length 1 is not equal to an array with those dimensions removed, for example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.shape
(3, 1)
>>> b.shape
(3,)
>>> a + a
array([[2],
       [4],
       [6]])
>>> a + b
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Conceptually, the difference between an array of shape `(3, 1)` and one of shape `(3,)` is like the difference between the length of `[100]` and `100`.

`[100]` is a `list` that happens to have *one* element. It could have more, but right now it has the *minimum possible number of elements*.

On the other hand, it doesn't even make sense to talk about the length of `100`, because it doesn't have one.

Similarly, the array of shape `(3, 1)` has 3 rows and 1 column, while the array of shape `(3,)` has *no columns at all*. It doesn't even have rows, in a sense; it *is* a row, just like `100` has no elements, because it *is* an element.

For more information on how differently shaped arrays behave when interacting with other arrays, you can see the [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Lastly, for completeness, to iterate through the rows of a `numpy` array, you could just do `for row in array`. If you want to iterate through the back axes, you can use `np.moveaxis`, for example:

```
>>> array = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> for row in array:
...     print(row)
...
[1 2]
[3 4]
[5 6]
>>> for col in np.moveaxis(array, [0, 1], [1, 0]):
...     print(col)
...
[1 3 5]
[2 4 6]
```

Comment: So can I say that in practice, more likely I should create data structure of (3,1), instead of (3,), because the latter isn't a typical object that operates on the concepts of dimensions, i.e. rows and columns?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to represent; there's no general rule.

Comment: @marlon: Don't think of rows and columns as fundamental and the absence of rows and columns as unnatural. One-dimensional vectors are just as natural as 0-dimensional scalars, two-dimensional matrices, and higher-dimensional tensors. The appropriate choice of dimensionality is not always 2; it depends on what you need to represent.